# Python: Is there a way to print even numbers within an unknown range and without if statement?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a homework to do in Python class and was given this question:

> Make a program that gets 2 numbers from the user, and prints all even
>   numbers in the range of those 2 numbers, you can only use as many for
>   statements as you want, but can't use another loops or if statement.

I understand that I need to use this code:

```
for num in range (x,y+1,2):
    print (num)
```

but without any `if` statements, I can't check if the value `x` inserted is even or odd, and if the user inserted the number `5` as `x`, all the prints will be odd numbers.

I also tried to enter each number to a tuple or an array, but I still can't check if the first number is even to start printing.

```
def printEvenFor(x,y):
    evenNumbers =[]
    for i in range (x,y+1):
        evenNumbers.append(i)
    print (evenNumbers[::2])
```

or

```
def printEvenFor(x,y):
    for i in range (x,y+1,2):
        print(i,",")
```

I expect the output of `printEvenFor(5,12)` to be `6,8,10,12` but it is `5,7,9,11`

Comment: you are missing the main check `i % 2 ==0`:

Comment: `list(range(5+1,12+1, 2))` (or more generically `list(range(x+x%2,y+y%2, 2))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make x even, by using floor division and then multiplication:

```
x = (x // 2) * 2
```

x will then be rounded to the previous even integer or stay the same if it was even before.

If you want to round it to the following even integer you need to do:

```
x = ((x + 1) // 2) * 2
```

This can be improved further by using shifting operators:

```
x = (x >> 1) << 1         #Alternative 1
x = ((x + 1) >> 1) << 1   #Alternative 2
```

Examples:

```
#Alternative 1
x = 9
x = (x >> 1) << 1
#x is now 8

#Alternative 2
x = 9
x = ((x + 1) >> 1) << 1
#x is now 10
```

The second one is probably more suitable for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use reminder to get the correct range:

```
def print_event_for(min_, max_):
    reminder = min_ % 2
    for i in range(min_+reminder, max_+reminder, 2):
        print(i)

print_event_for(5, 12)
```

Output:

```
6
8
10
12
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is by using while, that takes the start and end  range in

```
for each in range(int(input()),int(input())):
    while each%2 == 0:
       print (each)
       break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
x = x+x%2
for num in range (x,y+1,2):
    print (num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> for n in range((x + 1) // 2 * 2, y+1, 2):
        print(n)
```

The first argument to `range` forces it to be the next even number if it is odd. The last argument goes up in twos.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printEvenfor(x,y):
    return list(range(((x+1) // 2) * 2,y+1, 2))

printEvenfor(9,16)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function will do what you want. I use `round` to force the boundaries to be even in order to get start the range on an even number.

```
def print_even_between(x, y):
    x = round(x / 2) * 2
    y = round(y / 2) * 2

    for i in range(x, y, 2):
        print(i)  
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacky but fun: multiplying strings with zero.

```
>>> low, high = int(input()), int(input())
5
13
>>> for n in range(low, high + 1):
...     print('{}\n'.format(n)*(not n%2), end='')
... 
6
8
10
12
```

Odd numbes are not printed because the string is multiplied with `False` (acting as zero).